# How to convert a string to a 24hr time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a JSON returning times like "10:00am"> i need to create an array with eight other times from the current system time. so it would go like "10:00am, 11:00am, 12:00pm, 1:00am, etc"

Here's my current code so far:

```
   var katie=new Array();
   var webdate = new Date().getHours();
   var firsthr = day.date.start.time;
   for (i=0; i<=8; i++){
      katie{i] = webdate;
      webdate = webdate +1;       
   }
```

Comment: What is `var firsthr = day.date.start.time;` supposed to do? Also, why do you have a variable named `katie`? I know you can call your variables whatever you like, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to actually do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this .

```
      var str=new Array();
      var webdate = new Date();
          for (i=0; i<=8; i++){
               webdate.setHours(i);       
               str[i] = webdate;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is a very helpful library for parsing strings into dates.
On this [api doc page](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) for Date.js search for ".parse".  Also, the [FormatSpecifiers page](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) is helpful for converting dates to a string.

You said you have a JSON with the string, "10:00am".  Assuming this JSON,

```
var data = {time: "10:00am"};
```

You could create a date object like this:

```
 var date = Date.parse(data.time);
 // this will create a date object with today's date and time set to 10am
```

Then, you can use your loop to increment the time to hours past 10am.  Altogether it could look like this

```
<script src="date.js"></script>
<script>

var data = {time: "10:00am"};
var date = Date.parse(data.time);

//push today @ 10am
var katie=new Array(new Date(date));
for (i=0; i<=8; i++){
  //add an hour to date, then push new Date object based on date
  date.add({hours:1});
  katie.push(new Date(date));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
      var str=new Array();
      var webdate = new Date();
          var currenthours = webdate.getHours();
          var looplimit = currenthours + 8;
          for (i=currenthours; i<looplimit; i++){
               webdate.setHours(i);       
               str[i] = webdate.getHours() >= 12 ? webdate.getHours() -12 +':00pm' : webdate.getHours() +':00am';
          }
      }
```